# What is a Matrix Table?

Tags: database, matrix

Can somebody give me a picture as to what Matrix Tables are in the area of Database and the context in which they are best used ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but since no one answered this yet, I'll give it a try.

The context is indeed Database related, but more specifically it is **Data-Mining** related.
Matrix Tables are used for decision making and taking probabilities into account.

I hope the following sources can assist you further:

1. Section 1.2 of [Matrix Methods in Data Mining and Pattern Recognition](http://www.mai.liu.se/~laeld/matrix-methods/Chap1.pdf) (PDF).
2. Sections 3.1.1 & 3.1.4.2 of Oracle's [Predictive Data Mining Models](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10698_01/3predict.htm).

~ Amnon